# How do I track a branch of another repository on the same machine?

Tags: git

I have two private repositories on one machine.  Let's call them repo-A and repo-B, which are the directories ~/repo-A and ~/repo-B, respectively.  repo-A has two relevant branches: master and live.  I'd like to set up repo-B to track repo-A's live branch, so that `git pull` will pull any updates from repo-A's live branch into repo-B's master branch.  Right now, I have the following in repo-B's .git/config:

```
[remote "origin"]
        url = /home/stutzbach/repo-A/
        fetch = +refs/heads/live:refs/remotes/origin/live
[branch "master"]
        remote = origin
        merge = refs/heads/master
```

However, when I run `git pull`, it seems to pull from repo-A's master branch.  Obviously, I don't have it set up right.  What's the right way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've pasted exactly the bit of the config that's causing that:

```
[branch "master"]
        remote = origin
        merge = refs/heads/master
```

That's telling it to merge (which is part of pull) from the master branch of origin. Change it to `refs/heads/live` and you'll have what you want.